# How to list files from multiple environments?

Tags: salt-stack

I am having the following configuration on fileserver_backend.conf

```
fileserver_backend:
  - gitfs
  - roots

gitfs_provider: pygit2


gitfs_remotes:
  - http://x.git:
    - name: x
    - root: /
    - user: x
    - password: x
    - insecure_auth: True
    - base: master
    - saltenv:
      - master:
        - ref: master
    - mountpoint: salt://gitfs
```

listing the files from fileserver I am getting by default only the files in base environment.

```
salt-run fileserver.file_list
```

**Version is: 3004.2**

How I will make visible all the files from both environments (base & master) enviroment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fileserver.file_list` takes a `saltenv` argument to specify the environment:

```bash
salt-run fileserver.file_list saltenv=master
```

If you want files from both sources to be available in the same environment, you have to put them in the same environment. By default, the `master` branch will already be mapped to the `base` environment with no further configuration.

Documentation:

- https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/runners/all/salt.runners.fileserver.html#salt.runners.fileserver.file_list
- https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/configuration/master.html#std-conf_master-gitfs_remotes

Comment: **I am getting this when running a state with the following:**

'code'
include:
  - gitfs.test.newfileconfig 
'code'


**Specified SLS gitfs.test.newfileconfig in saltenv base is not available on the salt master or through a configured fileserver**

Comment: ok, do you have a file `/gitfs/test/newfileconfig.sls` in either your file roots or git repo?

Comment: I have the file in git repo

Comment: Then you need to do some additional debugging that is not suited to the Stack Overflow format.